# ¿Por qué Laravel me devuelve el error "Class 'HTML' not found" cuando utilizo un fichero CSS para una vista?

Tags: css, laravel-5

Quiero utilizar un fichero .css para dar estilo a una vista.

El fichero lo tengo en public/css y se llama imagen.css y por ahora solo tiene esto:

```
#foto_id{
    color:00FFFF;
}
```

Y para que las vistas lo utilicen uso este código:

```
{{ HTML::style('css/imagen.css') }}
```

Pero me sale este mensaje de error:

> ```
> Class 'HTML' not found (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bolsa\resources\views\formularios\articulo_crear.blade.php)
> ```

¿Qué falla aquí?

Comment: Te falta un `#` delante del valor: `color: #00FFFF`

Comment: te sale ese error por que `laravel collective` desde la versión 5 no se incluye por defecto, debes incluirlo usando composer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En primer lugar te falta en signo `#` en color hexadecimal, debería ser así;

```
#foto_id{
    color:#00FFFF;
}
```

Los `assets` se agregan de la siguiente manera según la documentación oficial, siempre y cuando estén dentro del directorio publico;

```
{{ asset('css/imagen.css') }}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" {{ asset('css/imagen.css') }}">
```

Comment: Vale, ahora si que funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a cambiar de todo mayúsculas a solo la primera en `HTML` además de usar la doble exclamación:

```
{!! Html::style('css/imagen.css') !!}
```